# Maintaining global but changeable variables across classes/packages

Tags: java, oop

I want to maintain some global variables that can be changed in Java. And once the state/value of a variable changes, next time I use this variable I should have the new changed state/value.

For example I use a config property and once changed, the new value should be used thereafter.

I am not able to figure out how to achieve this in Java. Any suggestions would be very helpful.

Comment: All you need is a singleton. And after that, just make sure all uses of that config reads from the singleton without caching locally.

Comment: Thanks @Joachim . Its very useful and also learned something new.